# FirstOrDefault vs IsNullOrDefault

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

Can I convert or use this IsNullOrDefault some how like FirstOrDefault what I mean without specify TSource? Or how should I modify the method to make it similar to FirstOrDefault.

`someList.FirstOrDefault()` <<< simple and clean

`someValue.IsNullOrDefault<int>()`  <<<  I don't want to say in here that this is int

```
    public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(this T argument)
    {
        // deal with normal scenarios
        if (argument == null) return true;
        if (object.Equals(argument, default(T))) return true;

        // deal with non-null nullables
        Type methodType = typeof(T);
        if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(methodType) != null) return false;

        // deal with boxed value types
        Type argumentType = argument.GetType();
        if (argumentType.IsValueType && argumentType != methodType)
        {
            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(argument.GetType());
            return obj.Equals(argument);
        }

        return false;
    }



public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source
)
```

Comment: You don't have to change it at all - it should be fine.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you might just want to add a check for `argument == DBNull.Value` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ infers the type based on the value provided; if you supply an int value to the method, it will be infer the type for you, as long as T is used in both the generic definition and in the argument.